# Is it possible to test a non https function with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a local function that is called like so:

```js
exports.testFunction = functions.pubsub
  .schedule(schedule)
  .onRun(() => test.scraper('123'))
```

However, `test.scraper()` is not an HTTPS function, it's just a regular function.

How can I test it using firebase without having to wrap it in a callable https function? Do I have to use the function shell?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to apply a standard JavaScript testing framework that works completely independently of Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug said, you can test this separately if that's what you need. However, according to the official documentation, you can also use offline unit [tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#stubbed-data) if it suits your workflow. You still have to wrap some functions, but it satisfies testing.

Example from the [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#stubbed-data) with stubbed data and [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/):

```
// Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:pushId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
      const original = snapshot.val();
      console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.pushId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
      // writing to the Firebase Realtime Database.
      // Setting an "uppercase" sibling in the Realtime Database returns a Promise.
      return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```